# Spark limit number of executors per service

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

We are using Spark streaming (java) for real time computation. Deployment has 6 node spark cluster (config setting is for 200 executors across nodes).

Currently there is one service which was publishing events in Rabbitmq queue. Now we are planning to add two more services. In case I create spark receiver per queue, is it possible to limit maximum number of executors that can serve one service in case of load scenario (say max limit 50%. So in above case at max 100 executors can serve streams receiving from service/receiver)?

Thanks 
Shishir

Answer (score 0):

[Explore](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#dynamic-allocation) below spark job property it will solve your problem.

for min resource  (spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors)

for max resource (spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors)

Comment: Sorry for late reply. Here Back pressure configuration is at Consumer, so in case receiver consuming from 2 different queue than same back pressure applies on both. We want to receiver to consume events with different back pressure/rate from each queue (I.e. 150 Message from Queue A and 50 from Queue B)